# Can't select all text in Excel cell (neither with CTRL+A)

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to select all text when I am inside cell ?

[image]

neither SELECT ALL appears, nor CTRL+A does anything.
(p.s. I am interested only when I am inside cell "EDIT MODE", not clicking the cell itself and copying).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get your cursor to the end of the text in the cell, try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>.

Alternatively, if you can get your cursor to the start of the text in the cell, try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>.

Comment: however, i am surprised why CTRL+A doesnt work. why MS managed to do that. 
THANKS !

Comment: ..............Very interesting and useful....................

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to create custom shortcut. This script will only remap CTRL+A if Excel is the active window.

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
#If  WinActive("ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE")
^a:: 
Send {Home}
Send ^+{End}
return

#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the cells are in the same region, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd>. Such a shortcut is commonly used for selecting the current region (i.e. a contiguous block of cells) around the active cell.